# Trying to populate forms from Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Im Trying to populate Form questions with dropdown list from google sheets and  it's coming out as an error when populating. [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n74t.png) I'm using App script

Here's the script I used.

```
function getDataFromGoogleSheets() {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
 const [header, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 const choices = {}
 header.forEach(function(title, index) {
  choices[title] = data.map(row => row[index]).filter(e => e !== "");
 });
 return choices;

}

function  populateGoogleForms() {
 const GOOGLE_FORM_ID = "1BY4-PDCuiL_ypwnRqqfwpAtEYg-IepAoRqM07_YPLVs"
 const googleForm = FormApp.openById(GOOGLE_FORM_ID);
 const items = googleForm.getItems();
 const choices = getDataFromGoogleSheets();
 items.forEach(function(item) {
  const itemTitle = item.getTitle();
  if (itemTitle in choices) {
   const itemType = item.getTitle();
   switch (itemType) {
    case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
     item.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
     break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
     item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
     break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.MULPTIPLE_CHOICE:
     item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
     break;
    default:
     
     console.log('Failed with error %s', itemTitle);
   }
  }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed a couple of misspellings in your code.

one of the problems is using the getTitle for the itemType

```
const itemType = item.getTitle();
//change it to 
const itemType = item.getType();
```

The other one is for the multiplechoice option.

```
case FormApp.ItemType.MULPTIPLE_CHOICE:
//change it to
case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
```

by updating those you code should work just fine.

```
function  populateGoogleForms() {
 const GOOGLE_FORM_ID = "1BY4-PDCuiL_ypwnRqqfwpAtEYg-IepAoRqM07_YPLVs"
 const googleForm = FormApp.openById(GOOGLE_FORM_ID);
 const items = googleForm.getItems();
 const choices = getDataFromGoogleSheets();
 items.forEach(function(item) {
 const itemTitle = item.getTitle();
 if (itemTitle in choices) {
  const itemType = item.getType();
  switch (itemType) {
   case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
    item.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
   break;
   case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
    item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
   break;
   case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
    item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
   break;
   default:
  
    console.log('Failed with error %s', itemTitle);
   }
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it @Matias. this worked. didn't notice the mispelling at all

Comment: Glad my answer helped you sort out the issue @Jean Philippe Fournier. When a post's answer solves the problem, it's a good idea for the person who asked the question to mark it as the correct answer. It helps others who might face the same problem later on.